# find zero weight cycles in a directed graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, weighted-graphs

I need to plan an algorithm that decides if a directed weighted graph $G = (V,E)$  has a zero weight cycle.

- the graph has no negtive cycles
- the algorithm needs to be in $O(|V| \cdot |E|)$ time

---

my idea was to first add a vertex (called $r$) and connect it to all of the vertices in the graph.
and then use the Bellman-Ford algorithm in some kind of way from $r$.
but I can't figure out how to change the algorithm in that kind of way to find a zero weighted cycle.

Comment: Can we assume integral weights on the edges?

Comment: @Inuyasha Yagami we have a weight function w:E-->R

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bellman-Ford and zero-distance cycle](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28897/bellman-ford-and-zero-distance-cycle)