# Detecting cycles with weight zero in a directed graph

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs

I am given a directed graph $G=(V, E)$ with a weight function $w: E\to\mathbb{R}$, that doesn't contain negative cycles.

I need to find an algorithm that returns `true` if and only if there is a cycle with weight zero in the graph.

The time complexity needs to be $O(|V||E|)$, so I thought about using Bellman-Ford algorithm, but I have two problems with that:

First, the graph doesn't necessarily connected, so I can't pick an arbitrary source vertex for the algorithm.

Second, I can't figure out how the algorithm can help me, and what I can do with its output.

I know that a [similar question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28897/bellman-ford-and-zero-distance-cycle) have been asked, but the answer just suggests to run Bellman-Ford algorithm, but as I mentioned, I can't choose a source vertex. In addition, I don't understand why the suggested answer will work at all.

Comment: The graph isn't necessarily connected... So find and process each connected component separately.

Comment: I have added the proof of the statement that was left as an exercise by D,W. You will be able to understand it now. Check the proof: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/134819/107966

Answer (score 1):

Add a new vertex $s_0$.  Add edges of weight 0 from $s_0$ to each other vertex.  Now you have a graph with a source vertex $s_0$.  Run [the previously mentioned algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/28907/755) on this new graph, using $s_0$ as the source vertex.